# Fetch User email in Salesforce Community Head Markup

Tags: javascript, lightning-community

In the Salesforce Community Page, under Experience Builder--> Settings-->Advance-->Head Markup, How can I reference user email information in the Head Markup script

Answer (score 0):

You will have to expose the user info using a Rest Apex class and then fetch the service in the Head markup using javascript